In the movie Oddity, why does Dani set up a camera to take photos at a given interval?
In the movie, Oddity, Dani is renovating a mansion she and her husband just purchased. She has a camera that has been set up to take photos at a given interval.
I am wondering why she would do this? The reason I can think of is to keep memories of how their mansion is being transformed / decorated over time. But I am not sure.

out-of-universe (as i have not seen this), that's quite a common thing to do on a project. Put it on a timeline and you get a cool time lapse of the project progressing, and renovating is one of those big projects that people sometimes like to do that on... https://youtu.be/vyC0A_zy9bk

@blobbymcblobby, yeah, I would say it is the reason.
